# How to cast a group of objects to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

There is a source object:

```js
var json = {
  results: [
    {
      name: 'Name1',
      volume: 1,
      lists: [
        {
          list: 1,
          tags: ['hello', 'world']
        },
        {
          list: 2,
          tags: ['hello']
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Name2',
      volume: 2,
      lists: [
        {
          list: 1,
          tags: ['world']
        },
        {
          list: 2,
          tags: ['hello', 'internet']
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

need to bring to an array of objects for all tags

```js
var array = [
  {
    volume: 1,
    list: 1,
    tags: 'hello'
  },
  {
    volume: 1,
    list: 1,
    tags: 'world'
  },
  {
    volume: 1,
    list: 2,
    tags: 'hello'
  },
  {
    volume: 2,
    list: 1,
    tags: 'world'
  },
  {
    volume: 2,
    list: 2,
    tags: 'hello'
  },
  {
    volume: 2,
    list: 2,
    tags: 'internet'
  }
];
```

BUT, the location in the source object can change, so it is advisable to use some kind of [dot-object](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/get-value) library to specify only `results.*.lists.*.tags.*` And print all matches to a string.

I am sure that the necessary library exists, I can not find.

I do not ask for a solution, I am almost sure that there is already such an npm package that can split an object into an array by key, just tell me the name.

Comment: "*the location in the source object can change*" that is very bad. Any reason why?

Comment: In different APIs, data is served in different formats (example `volume: 1` `volume: {num: 1}`). I need to bring everything to a single standard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will give you the desired output not considering your location change problem

Performance: O(N^3)

```js
var json = {
  results: [{
      name: 'Name1',
      volume: 1,
      lists: [{
          list: 1,
          tags: ['hello', 'world']
        },
        {
          list: 2,
          tags: ['hello']
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Name2',
      volume: 2,
      lists: [{
          list: 1,
          tags: ['world']
        },
        {
          list: 2,
          tags: ['hello', 'internet']
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const result = json.results.reduce((acc1, x) => ([...acc1,
  ...x.lists.reduce((acc2, y) => ([...acc2,
    ...y.tags.reduce((acc3, z) => ([...acc3, {
      volume: x.volume,
      list: y.list,
      tags: z
    }]), [])
  ]), [])
]), [])

console.log(result);
```